# Proportional Editing is not working, object is moving

Tags: edit-mode

Have a question about Proportional editing. When I choose the vertice, then press O, and press G - as result my object is moving completely unstead of editing. Please advise what can be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the radius by scrolling the mouse wheel after pressing G?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Just tried and it's works!

Comment: It's a good idea to take a look at Blender's manual for questions like this: [page on proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html#influence)

Answer (score 2):

Lower the proportional editing influence using the mouse wheel.

[image]